# Servicestack GetAsync OnSuccess not fired

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack to prototype a web service API, and have hit an issue when testing GetAsync. Specifically, the onSuccess action is not called when I expect it to be.

Here's my code:

Server:

```
[Route("/accounts/", "GET")
public class AccountRequest : IReturn<AccountResponse>
{
    public string EmailAddress {get; set;}
}

public class AccountResponse
{
    public Account Account {get; set;}
}

public class AccountService : Service
{
    public object Get(AccountRequest request)
    {
        return new AccountResponse{Account = new Account.....
    }
}
```

Very basic, pretty much as per hello world examples on [ServiceStack.net](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/)

And the offending Client GetAsync call:

```
using(var client = new JsonServiceClient("some url")
{
    client.GetAsync(new AccountRequest{EmailAddress = "gibbons"},
            response => Console.WriteLine(response.Account.Something), //This never happens
            (response, ex) => {throw ex;}); // if it matters, neither does this

}
```

However, this works exactly as expected...

```
using(var client = new JsonServiceClient("some url")
{
    var acc = client.Get(new AccountRequest{EmailAddress = "gibbons"});

    //acc is exactly as expected.
}
```

And interestingly, testing async and non-async one after the other works too:

```
using(var client = new JsonServiceClient("some url")
{
     client.GetAsync(new AccountRequest{EmailAddress = "gibbons"},
                    response => Console.WriteLine(response.Account.Something), //Works
                    (response, ex) => {throw ex;});

    var acc = client.Get(new AccountRequest{EmailAddress = "gibbons"});

    //Again, acc is exactly as expected.
}
```

In all cases, I can see the actual data being transferred over HTTP via Fiddler, so I think i'm missing some fundamental understanding of how the async api works.

Any help most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocking synchronous APIs don't return until the response is finished where as the Async APIs are non-blocking so execution continues straight away. The callbacks are only fired when the response is returned and processed.

In the [AsyncRestClientTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AsyncRestClientTests.cs) tests, it sleeps for 1 sec with `Thread.Sleep(1000)` before asserting that a response was returned in time.

How long are you waiting to determine if the callback is fired?

Comment: Yep - I just wasn't waiting long enough for the response. Thanks.